# Como somar valores referentes a uma linha, buscada com a função Índice + Corresp no Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Queria somar alguns valores referentes aos nomes dados para as células "Ref 1, 2 e 3" somando todos os valores das colunas "N1, N2 e N3" de acordo com a "Ref" procurada, para isso eu utilizei essa fórmula: `=ÍNDICE(SOMA(C70:E72);CORRESP(F73;B70:B72;0))`, porém não deu certo! Pois era para da o resultado da soma da "Ref 2" que seria "50", que no caso seria a soma das coluna "N1, 2 e 3" da linha "Ref 2".

Alguma solução para esse erro??

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

De acordo com a sua planilha, a fórmula que vai ser inserida da célula F74 ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
=SOMA(ÍNDICE($B$70:$E$72;CORRESP($F$73;$B$70:$B$72;0);0))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a formula `Soma(Intervalo)`, junto com a `Somase(Intervalo,critério,intervalo_soma)`

Use assim: `=Soma(Somase(B70:B72,B71,C70:C72),Somase(B70:B72,B71,D70:D72),Somase(B70:B72,B71,E70:E72))`